# Mutable flags on a std::facet object

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create some I/O manipulators to allow a user to modify the output format of a custom type.

Say I have a `Foo` object: I might want to either output it in a nice, human-readable format (pretty printing), or I might want to print it in a condensed form to save space when serialized.

So, it would be nice to have custom I/O manipulators like `condensed` and `pretty` that would modify the internal flags of a facet, so I could say something like:

```
Foo f;

...

std::cout << pretty << f; // output human-readable format
std::cout << condensed << f; // output condensed format
```

The problem I always run into is the fact that once a facet object is created, it can only be retrieved later by using `std::use_facet`, which returns a *const* reference.  This means I can't later modify any of the internal facet flags.

Consider a simple facet:

```
class my_facet : public std::locale::facet
{
    public:

    my_facet() : m_pretty(false), m_condensed(false)
    { }

    void set_pretty(bool b) { m_pretty = b; }

    void set_condensed(bool b) { m_condensed = b; }

    static std::locale::id id;

    private:

    bool m_pretty;
    bool m_condensed;
};
```

I could then create I/O manipulators like:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits>
inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& pretty(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os)
{
    my_facet<CharT>* facet = new my_facet();
    facet->set_pretty(true);
    facet->set_condensed(false);
    std::locale loc = std::locale(os.getloc(), facet);
    os.imbue(loc);
    return os;
}
```

That works nicely... but what if I want to allow the user to specify additional flags or formatting options, like say, an `indentation` option that allows the user to specify a number of spaces to indent, like this:

```
std::cout << pretty << indent(4) << f;
```

The problem is that each I/O manipulator has to recreate the facet object, and so previous flags set are lost.  The reason is that there's no way to access a *non-const* reference to the existing facet.

I want to say:

```
template <class CharT, class Traits>
inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& operator << (std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
    const indent& ind)
{
    const my_facet<CharT>& facet = std::use_facet<my_facet>(os.getloc()); 
    facet.set_indentation(ind.value()); // Error: facet is const!
    return os;
}
```

...but of course, that won't work, because `facet` is `const`.  The only way I can see around this is making all internal flags `mutable`, which is absurd.

So, I'm sensing that I'm just doing this wrong.  There doesn't seem to be any way to get a non-const reference to an existing facet, so I think I'm going about this whole thing the wrong way.

So, how is this sort of thing usually achieved?  How can I write I/O manipulators that can be chained together to set different flags, like:

```
std::cout << pretty << indent(3) << etc ...
```

Comment: Store your formatting state and flags [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/xalloc) rather than in a facet.

Comment: @n.m.: Care to expand that into an answer? It is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted way of storing custom formatting state is with memory allocated by `std::ios_base::xalloc`. For example (abridged, [live demo with full code here](http://ideone.com/obgh5z)):

```
class MyFancyManipulator
{
    static int myidx;
    int st;
  public:
    MyFancyManipulator(int st) : st(st) {};
    template <typename Ch, typename Tr> friend
        std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<< (std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& str,
                const MyFancyManipulator& man) {
            //
            // Transfer state from the manipulator to the stream
            //
            str.iword(MyFancyManipulator::myidx) = man.st;
            return str;
        }
};

// Allocate index for the state variable
// This is thread safe per C++14 standard
int MyFancyManipulator::myidx = std::ios_base::xalloc();


// ... In some custom operator<<

   int state = str.iword(MyFancyManipulator::myidx);
```